# Foriegn_key overwrite and show some field problem. I want to restock my inventory product

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms

Foriegn_key overwrite and show some field problem. I want to restock my inventory product.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMBpE.png)

Comment: Please can you provide more info about problem and what exactly you want with example, thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.